# Windows 8 registration with wrong email

Tags: windows-8, setup

My grandparents have got a brand new Windows 8 laptop, and they have created an account, and they have bound it with an email address. The problem is that they entered a Gmail address, but it has to be a Microsoft email and I have no idea how to change it.

I know about "PC Settings" and that I can switch the account to a local account there, but I can't access it because it is impossible to log in with that Gmail account. Once, the *were* logged on, but then they turned off their computer and now there is no way to log in and fix the problem.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to recover it. Actually, there *was* a Microsoft account created with the Gmail address as email. I thought that it really had to be a Microsoft email, but I was wrong about that. I fixed it by going to account.live.com and clicked "Can't access your account?". Then I sent a recovery email to the Gmail account and recovered the Microsoft account by changing the password. Then I used the same password to log on to the Windows 8 computer, and I successfully logged in.

Comment: And just to add, even if they'd used the wrong email, e.g. your own email, they could just add a second user account, use the correct email, and then delete the initial account. There's no DRM involved that binds the installation to be used by any specific account. Only the opposite: You can use apps on your account on up to x different computers.